# Unable to bind docker container to secondary interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, centos

I have an EC2 instance (running CentOS 7) with two network interfaces on it. The primary is `ens5` and the secondary was attached as `eth0`. What I'm attempting to do is bind my docker container to `eth0`, so that both incoming and outgoing traffic is associated with the IP address of `eth0`.

I have a couple of external ports exposed. The first thing I tried in my `docker run` command was to just do `eth0_ip:port:port`. The container did start up successfully, and I was able to hit the container from the host on the IP of `eth0`, however when making requests from other EC2 instances in the same VPC, the requests timed out. Using `tcpdump` I was able to confirm that external requests *are* making it to the instance, however requests aren't making it to the container.

I also attempted to create a new network associated with the IP address of `eth0`, and then set the `--network` flag in my run command, but I was greeted with the same exact failure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!